# PHP array to tree array

Tags: php, arrays, tree, key

I have a problem I cannot fix. I have 2 arrays and a string. The first array contains the keys the second one should use. The first one is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => hello
)
```

Now I need a PHP code that converts it to the second array:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Array
                (
                    [hello] => MyString
                )
        )
)
```

The number of items is variable.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Walk the array back to front ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use references to solve this problem:

```
$a = array (0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar', 2 => 'hello' );

$b = array();
$ptr = &$b;
foreach ($a as $val) {
    $ptr[$val] = Array();
    $ptr = &$ptr[$val];
}
$ptr = 'MyString';
var_dump($b);
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that I didn't know the use of &.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is  :

```
$path = array(
        0 => 'foo',
        1 => 'bar',
        2 => 'hello'
);

$data = array();
$t = &$data;
foreach ( $path as $key ) {
    $t = &$t[$key];
}
$t = "MyString";
unset($t);

print_r($data);
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/13953)

Comment: Thanks, but Netme was a bit faster.